I met a bug when using remote_ip_proxy_scrubber to get the real IP
When I using this gem, I found out it might get the wrong response from server(rails version 6.1..6.1).
e.q.: I kept made 2 request calling, A is http://127.0.0.1/?value=dummy1 and B is http://127.0.0.1/?value=dummy2
Assume the api is very simple that only return the value sent.
That means A should get {value: "dummy1"}, B should get {value: "dummy2"}
Sometimes, B would get {value: "dummy1"}.
After I checked the project setting, I found out the problem is config.middleware.insert_before(Rails::Rack::Logger, RemoteIpProxyScrubber.filter_middleware, scrubbed_ips).
That is, if I marked this code, the problem solved. However, I still need this gem help me to scrub the ip.
here is my code in config/application.rb
    # Load the list of scrubbed IPs from the YAML file
    scrubbed_ips = JSON.parse(File.read(Rails.root.join('config', 'initializers', 'scrubbed_ips.json')))['scrubbed_ips']

    config.middleware.insert_before(Rails::Rack::Logger, RemoteIpProxyScrubber.filter_middleware, scrubbed_ips)
    config.middleware.insert_before(Rails::Rack::Logger, RemoteIpProxyScrubber.patched_logger)
    config.middleware.delete(Rails::Rack::Logger)

and the value in scrubbed_ips.json would be like:
{
  "scrubbed_ips": [
    "1.1.1.0/26",
    "2.2.2.0/26",
    .
    .
    .
    ]
}

Once the scrubbed_ips increased, the error rate would increased.
Also, once the api spent more time, the error rate would increased.
I had made a small test. Even if I only put 2 IPs in scrubbed_ips, there are also some errors might occurred.
Is there someone met the some bugs like this?

I am not entirely sure what you are saying but the gem you are referring to has not been touched in 9 years.

Indeed. However, I cannot find any gem to replace it. Also, I had updated the example.
